# What's the meaning of "die Schule schaffen"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of "die Schule schaffen", like in this sentence:

> Es hängt davon ab, ob er die Schule schafft.

I googled it but found nothing helpful in english, with [dict cc](https://m.dict.cc/german-english/es+auf+die+h%C3%B6here+Schule+schaffen.html) showing something similar but (I think) unrelated.

Comment: Please use [google translate](https://translate.google.com/) or [deepl](https://www.deepl.com/translator) with the sentence... both return valid and correct translations... This platform is not here to answer questions that translation sites can answer easily...

Comment: @Tode That is poor advice. How is a learner supposed to know whether a given translation is correct? Or whether the translation given by the tool is the only correct one?

Comment: @David Vogt: It's true that automatic translators only get it 90% right, and then only 90% of the time, but an English speaker should know when the translation makes sense to a human and if it fits the context. There are no idioms in the sentence, and really the hard part is *schaffen*, whose meaning varies wildly depending on the object its paired with. At the least, the question should include a machine translation and some explanation as to why it doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Sorry, I don't understand. I just repeated what our [help about "on-topic" questions](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) sais: `If your question could be answered by a dictionary, a grammar book, or another general reference, consult these. Explain why this did not help you when asking your question.`. Just tried to explain my "Close"- vote...

Comment: @Tode "Can be translated via machine translation" is a new close reason for me, and one that I disagree with, for the reasons stated in my previous comment.

Comment: I have seen plenty of machine translations that made sense to a human, fit the context, and were wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verb "schaffen" has several meanings, but in this case, it means something like "to be successful at", "to achieve". Knowing that, [your result on dict.cc](https://m.dict.cc/german-english/es+auf+die+h%C3%B6here+Schule+schaffen.html) is actually closely related, even though it is a slightly more complex construction than just ["schaffen" with an accusative object](https://m.dict.cc/deen/?s=schaffen).

Now, said accusative object of "schaffen" usually denotes something that involves some kind of a test that needs to be accomplished (but that can realistically be failed, as well):

- eine Prüfung schaffen
- den Abschluss schaffen
- eine Aufgabe schaffen

Thus, "die Schule schaffen" is a shorter way of saying something like "alle Prüfungen an der Schule bis hin zum Abschluss bestehen" - in other words, "to manage to graduate from school".

The difference to just saying "to graduate from school" is that the latter is just a description of what happens in terms of the subject's school career, whereas "schaffen" also conveys a sense of accomplishment; that said graduation is not guaranteed.

Comment: Supplement: *schaffen* is a verb with many meanings so I advise to check a dictionary anyway. Note that *den Lehrer schaffen* (colloquial) can have the entire different meaning of achieving to get the teacher exhausted or even near to a nervous breakdown.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually knew that schaffen means something similar to "accomplish" or "achieve", but it has other (for me) confusing meanings, like "create", or //den Zug schaffen// meaning "catch the train"...so I didn't know if //die Schule schaffen// means "succeed at school", "catch up with your peers at school" or even "create the school".

Comment: I even came across a sentence where //die Schule schaffen// was translated as "gradute from school", but as I said before, I was confused between the different possible meanings of the verb schaffen: //Laut Schulmedizinischer Auskunft von damals, hätte er niemals eine normale Schule schaffen können, und wäre auf einem geistigen Niveau von einem Kleinkind stehen geblieben.//

Comment: @KeNSmilePachI: I'd say "den Zug schaffen" is exactly the same meaning as described in my answer: You manage to arrive in time to get on the train, which may, for one reason or another, have easily failed.